# Android custom view added to window consume and dispatch touch event by condition

Tags: android, view, window, touch-event

I add a custom view into window at a foreground service, the view need to consume the touch event when user touch specific area in the custom view, otherwise, the touch event should dispatch to the views behind the custom view.

The problem is the custom view consume the touch event always, no matter true or false value return from onTouchEvent, but once I change the flag from WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL to WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE, then the custom view never accept touch events which are respond by the views behind the custom view.

Add view in foreground service:

```
private void addView() {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    if (null == mView) {
        mView = new AntiPeepView(this);
    }
    wm.addView(mView, params);
    LogUtil.d(TAG, "addView");
}
```

Override onTouchEvent in the custom view:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            calculateDragPoint(event);
            DragPoint dp = mDragPoint;
            if (dp.equals(DragPoint.MISS)) {
                LogUtil.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent", "down false");
                return super.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
            mDownX = event.getX();
            mDownY = event.getY();

            if (dp.equals(DragPoint.TOP)) {
                mTopDownY = mDownY;
            } else if (dp.equals((DragPoint.BOTTOM))) {
                mBottomDownY = mDownY;
            }
            LogUtil.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent", "down true");
            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            float moveX = clampX(event.getX());
            float moveY = clampY(event.getY());
            if (DragPoint.TOP.equals(mDragPoint)) {
                // Can't drag horizontally at present.
                //mTopDragPointX = moveX;
                if (Math.abs(moveY - mDownY) >= shreldHold) {
                    mTopRectBottom = (int) moveY;
                    mTopRect.set(mTopRect.left, mTopRect.top, mTopRect.right, mTopRectBottom);
                }
            } else if (DragPoint.BOTTOM.equals(mDragPoint)) {
                mBottomDragPointX = moveX;
                mAlpha = (int) (255 * moveX / getWidthRange());
                if (Math.abs(moveY - mDownY) >= shreldHold) {
                    mBottomRectTop = (int) moveY;
                    mBottomRect. set(mBottomRect.left, mBottomRectTop, mBottomRect.right,
                            mBottomRect.bottom);
                }
            }

            invalidate();
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            LogUtil.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent", "up");
            resetDragPoint();
            break;

        default:
            break;

    }
    LogUtil.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent", "end");
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```